# Using the ASP.NET MVC Attribute Based Route Mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I want to use [this ASP.NET MVC Attribute Based Route Mapper](http://maproutes.codeplex.com/), first announced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894779/asp-net-mvc-routing-via-method-attributes/2195438#2195438).

So far, I understand how to implement code that uses it, but I've run into a few questions that I think those who have used this attribute-based route mapper in the past will be able to answer.

- **How do I use it with ActionResults that are for `HTTP POST`s?** In other words, how does it work with form submissions and the like? Should I just put the URL of the `GET` method in, or should I use the `GET` method URL without any parameters (as in `HTTP POST` they aren't passed in through the URL)?
- **How do I use it with "URL querystring parameters"?** Can the attribute be configured to map to a route such as `/controller/action?id=value` rather than `/controller/action/{id}`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I use it with ActionResults
>   that are for HTTP POSTs?

You decorate the action that you are posting to with the `[HttpPost]` attribute:

```
[Url("")]
public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }

[Url("")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string id) { return View(); }
```

If you decide to give the POST action a different name:

```
[Url("")]
public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }

[Url("foo")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string id) { return View(); }
```

You need to supply this name in your helper methods:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("foo", "home", new { id = "123" })) { %>
```

---

> How do I use it with "URL querystring
>   parameters"?

Query string parameters are not part of the route definition. You can always obtain them in a controller action either as action parameter or from `Request.Params`.

As far as the `id` parameter is concerned it is configured in `Application_Start`, so if you want it to appear in the query string instead of being part of the route simply remove it from this route definition:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoutes();
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

Comment: For the first part: does anything change if my GET route is something like `/controller/action/{param}` rather than just `""`? For the second part: Doesn't the default ASP.NET MVC routing control map all querystring parameters (not just `id`)?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Query string parameters (?param1=value1&param2=value2&...) are automatically handled by ASP.NET and are not part of the route. They are not mapped. You map a parameter when it is part of the route like `{controller}/{action}/{someParam}`.