# ASP.NET MVC - Routing still confusing for me

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, routes, controller

I'm having difficulty with the concept of Routing within the ASP.NET MVC Framework. For example, I have a controller method:

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
   public ActionResult GetChildFolders(string id)
   {

       IEnumerable<MyModel> list = MyModelDataContext.GetChildFolders( new Guid(id) );

       IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listitems = list.Select(row => new SelectListItem
                                                           {
                                                               Value = row.FolderID.ToString(),
                                                               Text = row.FolderName
                                                           });

       return this.Json(listitems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

and here's my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "UploadRoute", // Route name
   "Upload/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Upload", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional 
});
```

Now, if I have two jQuery functions:

```
function TeamChange1() {
  var id = $('#TeamList').val();
  $.getJSON('/Upload/GetChildFolders/' + id, null, function(data) {
      bindOptionResults(data);
  });
}

function TeamChange2() {
  var id = $('#TeamList').val();
  $.getJSON('/Upload/GetChildFolders', id, function(data) {
      bindOptionResults(data);
  });
}
```

TeamChange1() will call the GetChildFolders() method with the id parameter properly wired up and filled in, however, with TeamChange2() the id parameter remains null in the controller method. This must be a routing issue that causes this. What is the explaination?

Comment: You didn't post the GetChildFolders route. I imagine it's the same. On another subject, you might be interested in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894779/asp-net-mvc-routing-via-method-attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need routing here. In fact the default route `{controller}\{action}\{id}` matches your controller, action, and parameter name (`id`) already so defining `UploadRoute` is redundant.

The reason TeamChange2() doesn't work is because `id` is a string, not an object. The proper code is:

```
function TeamChange2() {
  var id = $('#TeamList').val();
  $.getJSON('/Upload/GetChildFolders', {id: id}, function(data) {
      bindOptionResults(data);
  });
}
```

This will pass `id` in the params collection instead of the url. MVC doesn't care and will still bind since the parameter name matches the `id` route parameter. Watch the requests in FireBug to see the difference.

Also, you can change your `id` parameter in the controller action to the Guid data type so you don't have to do `new Guid(id)` in the code.

Comment: How do I watch this kind of request in Firebug? That would be really useful. DOM tab?

Comment: It will be in the console tab. Be sure to open the tab when you first load the page. The first method should post to `/Upload/GetChildFolders/1234` and the second one will post to `/Upload/GetChildFolders`. If you expand the second one and look at the params tab, you will see `id: 1234` listed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the second func. The key thing is the structure of the post data
{name : value}

```
function TeamChange2() {
  $.getJSON('/Upload/GetChildFolders', {id : $('#TeamList').val()}, function(data) {
      bindOptionResults(data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not construct the URL in `TeamChange2` as you did in `TeamChange1` ?

```
function TeamChange2() {
  var id = $('#TeamList').val();
  $.getJSON('/Upload/GetChildFolders/' + id, null, function(data) {
      bindOptionResults(data);
  });
}
```

I believe that's how I usually do it.