# ASP.NET MVC Routing Via Method Attributes GET vs. POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, routes, url-routing

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I want to use this ASP.NET MVC Attribute Based Route Mapper, first announced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894779/asp-net-mvc-routing-via-method-attributes/2195438#2195438).

I am trying to do a RESTful API using this, and I don't understand how to differentiate from Get vs. post.

The GET is found, but when I try to POST, the route doesn't map, and I get a 404. Please advise.

See Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Url("organizations/{organizationId?}/alerts/", Order = 1)]
public JsonResult List(Guid? organizationId) {
    ...
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
[Url("organizations/{organizationId?}/alerts/", Order = 2)]
public JsonResult Send(Guid? organizationId, string message) {
    ...
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are peforming POST while testing to your POST route?

Comment: Another "duh" question: Your GET and POST methods have different route names; are you sure your POST is going to `Send` and not `List`?

Comment: What do you mean? They don't have different route names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Thechoyce for helping me. Simply renaming the send action to "List" fixed the problem. They need to both be the same to overload.

```
[HttpGet]
[Url("organizations/{organizationId?}/alerts/", Order = 1)]
public JsonResult List(Guid? organizationId) {
    ...
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
[Url("organizations/{organizationId?}/alerts/", Order = 2)]
public JsonResult List(Guid? organizationId, string message) {
    ...
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```