# Is there a way to find which url (as a string) matches a registered ASP.NET Route?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

If I have the following routes, each represented as a string:-

```
/account/index
/account  <-- which actually goes to /account/index
```

and these have been registered in my global.asax ... is there any way I can convert this into a Route object so I can then do this...

```
var routeName = FigureOutTheRegisteredRoute("/account");
return RedirectToRoute(routeName);
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You might find some ideas in Phil Haack's [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) - check out `DebugHttpHandler.cs` in particular...

Comment: i think the main magic with @haacked code would be this line:  `var vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext, rvalues);` .. but that would mean i would need to `new` up a `RequestContext`? Which means things could get real messy, quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Something as below - using RouteBase.

```
    RouteData rd = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
    rd.Values.Add("controller", controllername);
    rd.Values.Add("action", actionname);
    rd.Values.Add("url", url);
    return rd
```

[url-manipulation-implementing-routebase](http://dheemhi.blogspot.com/2010/12/url-manipulation-implementing-routebase.html)

**EDIT**

You can use [url-routing-debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to QUERY routable .. to see which registered route matches my url-string

use Nuget Package Manager Console - install-package routedebugger

you can query RouteCollection.  partial basic code as below

in

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
```

and

```
public static class RouteDebugger
{
    public static void RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        using (routes.GetReadLock())
        {
            bool foundDebugRoute = false;
            foreach (RouteBase routeBase in routes)
            {
                Route route = routeBase as Route;
                if (route != null)
                {
                    route.RouteHandler = new DebugRouteHandler();
                }

                if (route == DebugRoute.Singleton)
                    foundDebugRoute = true;

            }
            if (!foundDebugRoute)
            {
                routes.Add(DebugRoute.Singleton);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: nope. I don't want to add a new route to the routing table. I want to QUERY the routable .. to see which registered route matches my url-string.

Comment: @Pure.Krome - chekc out my edit also on above link i have added  url-manipulation-implementing-routebase for Phill's route debug link under references

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I don't fully understand why you would want to do that. ;-(

If you don't want to register multiple routes manually in global.asax then maybe want you want is to declare routes on your controllers using attributes? Check this answer: [ASP.NET MVC Routing Via Method Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894779/asp-net-mvc-routing-via-method-attributes/895176#895176)

Sorry if that's not what you're looking for...

Comment: Nope - that's not what i'm trying to do. Actually, it's the complete opposite. I'm trying to convert a string to it's corresponding registered route.