# MVC URL not rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

I'm trying to change the URL displayed in the user's browser from Happy/Balloons to happy-times/balloon-pops. There are many links in the project to the action "Balloons", so rather than change those links I'd like to change the global.asax so that a different URL appears for the same action. The original MVC Route looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Happy.Balloons",
            "Happy/Balloons/{groupId}/{paymentType}/{mortgageValue}/{province}",
            new { controller = "Happy", action = "Balloons" },
            new { groupId = "\\d+", paymentType = "\\d+", mortgageValue = "\\d+", province = "\\d+" }
        );
```

I've changed the code to

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Happy.Balloons",
            "happy-times/balloon-pops/{groupId}/{paymentType}/{mortgageValue}/{province}",
            new { controller = "Happy", action = "Balloons" },
            new { groupId = "\\d+", paymentType = "\\d+", mortgageValue = "\\d+", province = "\\d+" }
        );
```

I thought this second parameter was the URL displayed, but I'm getting a: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." error. Is there a simple way to do this by modifying parameters in MapRoute? If so, how?

Question Follow-up: [Change URL of action in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803290/change-url-of-action-in-mvc)

Comment: valen? a babylon 5 reference?

Comment: my name, actually. but now you've got me interested :)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

Changing the route mapping will not change the name of the controller.  Change the controller and action name, and map your route as `{controller}/{action}` like it is by default.  Then you can set your default controller and action as you have before.

Then your controller will have to be renamed to `happy-times` and your action renamed to `balloon-pops`

I should note that it will look more like this:

```
{controller}/{action}/{groupId}/{paymentType}/{mortgageValue}/{province}
```

Here's a good resource on the topic.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

as brought to you by this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375293/1178921

**Looks like you might be trying to see more ways to do this.

This post talks about attributes you can use to route URLS differently.
[ASP.NET MVC Routing Via Method Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894779/asp-net-mvc-routing-via-method-attributes)

Additionally, your way of changing the url in the mapping CAN work, but isn't what I thought your intent was.  [Zach dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802695/1178921) had this one dead on in that case.  Your optional parameters need to be marked as such with `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: So there is no way to rewrite a controller name when rendering a specific URL? That is, the URL will always have the same name as a controller? Thanks for the resources btw, will definitely give them a look and post any solution I come up with

Answer (score 2):

this works, (replacing urlParameter.Optional to default values)

```
routes.MapRoute( _
            "Happy.Balloons", _
            "happy-times/ballons-pops/{groupId}/{paymentType}/{mortgageValue}/{province}", _
            New With {.controller = "happy", .action = "Balloons", .groupId = UrlParameter.Optional, .paymentType = UrlParameter.Optional, .mortgageValue = UrlParameter.Optional, .province = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

but... it's a bad practice (really bad one)

you can learn about route maps [here](http://techjukebox.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/understanding-the-mvc-routing-process/)

Comment: What part you refer as "bed practice"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "bed practice" is something we all like :) sorry I cannot resist although I think it was typo. No hard feelings